# How to fix floating footer in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

My site's footer 'floats' in Chrome, leaving a white gap when scrolled down: [image]

This does not occur in Firefox or Edge. Checked CSS and HTML structure, not spotting any anomalies - relevant portion provided below. Any remedy?

Site: https://dragonnotes.org

---

```css
html {margin: 0; height: 100%}
body {margin: 0; height: 100%}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Arial; margin: 0;}

.footdiv6{
background: rgba(145,145,173,1);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,145,173,1) 0%, rgba(80,80,131,0.8) 10%, rgba(67,67,122,0.81) 12%, rgba(44,44,130,0.88) 25%, rgba(43,43,132,0.92) 32%, rgba(42,42,135,0.95) 39%, rgba(40,40,138,0.96) 49%, rgba(1,1,36,1) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(145,145,173,1)), color-stop(10%, rgba(80,80,131,0.8)), color-stop(12%, rgba(67,67,122,0.81)), color-stop(25%, rgba(44,44,130,0.88)), color-stop(32%, rgba(43,43,132,0.92)), color-stop(39%, rgba(42,42,135,0.95)), color-stop(49%, rgba(40,40,138,0.96)), color-stop(100%, rgba(1,1,36,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,145,173,1) 0%, rgba(80,80,131,0.8) 10%, rgba(67,67,122,0.81) 12%, rgba(44,44,130,0.88) 25%, rgba(43,43,132,0.92) 32%, rgba(42,42,135,0.95) 39%, rgba(40,40,138,0.96) 49%, rgba(1,1,36,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,145,173,1) 0%, rgba(80,80,131,0.8) 10%, rgba(67,67,122,0.81) 12%, rgba(44,44,130,0.88) 25%, rgba(43,43,132,0.92) 32%, rgba(42,42,135,0.95) 39%, rgba(40,40,138,0.96) 49%, rgba(1,1,36,1) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(145,145,173,1) 0%, rgba(80,80,131,0.8) 10%, rgba(67,67,122,0.81) 12%, rgba(44,44,130,0.88) 25%, rgba(43,43,132,0.92) 32%, rgba(42,42,135,0.95) 39%, rgba(40,40,138,0.96) 49%, rgba(1,1,36,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(145,145,173,1) 0%, rgba(80,80,131,0.8) 10%, rgba(67,67,122,0.81) 12%, rgba(44,44,130,0.88) 25%, rgba(43,43,132,0.92) 32%, rgba(42,42,135,0.95) 39%, rgba(40,40,138,0.96) 49%, rgba(1,1,36,1) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#9191ad', endColorstr='#010124', GradientType=0 );
}

.htp04{height:40px} .wi10{width:100%} .fs09{font-size:90%}
.wlink /* white color, hover-only underline */
```

```html
<html>
<head><!-- meta, link, title, script code--></head>
<!-- div code -->

<body>
<!-- div, a, img, li code-->
<!-- script code (JS); nothing fancy, just buttons-->
</body>

</html> 
<!-- header & footer implemented via PHP, e.g.
<?php include("PHP/header.php"); ?>  -->

<!-- complete footer code -->
<div style="transform:translateY(10px); margin-top:-10px" class="footdiv6 htp04 wi10">
<div class="fs09" style="margin-left:50px; margin-top:12px; color:white; float:left; font-weight:700">
Dragon Notes, &nbsp; Est. 2018 &ensp; &emsp; <a href="About.php" class="wlink">About</a></div>
<h4  class="fs09" style="margin-right:50px; margin-top:12px; margin-bottom: 0; color:white; float:right;">By OverLordGoldDragon</h4></div>
```

Comment: I guess it's because of different default values of properties in different browsers. Have a look on normalize.css e.g. and try if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<h4>` element within the footer was inserting a margin-bottom (effective in Chrome only) - gap's ridden once set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Div with class row that are inside modalPar is not long enough. thats why when you make the window smaller the div content stratch down and you get the expected result.

So Add `min-height: 82vh;` to the addition of `height:100%` for class row, should fix your problem.

Comment: Tried 82, 92, and 100 - no avail.

Comment: Well. i did try it with chrome developer tools and it works in you site.

Comment: Solved it - an inobvious fix